# Openpyxl "Numbers Stored as Text"

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

Background:

- Using Pycharm w/ Openpyxl
- I work a lot in Excel and have been trying to automate some small daily tasks using python to increase my understanding of the language

Situation:

- I am trying to modify an existing xlsx spreadsheet, and have been able to successfully change formatting like column width, zoom, etc.
- However, I am really struggling with the dreaded "Numbers stored as text" scenario. There is a specific range of columns (Z:AZ) that always contain numbers, but they are stored as text by default.

Question:

- Has anyone had experience converting text to numbers within an existing worksheet?

I've done some extensive searching on StackOverflow as well as many other sites and can't seem to find a solution that will work for me.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

As you are getting Numbers Stored as Text error, I believe that the value you are adding in the Excel worksheet is String.
Please confirm this by displaying type of your variable.

```
type(variable_name)
```

If it is `<class'str'>`, then add `int` while passing the variable to Excel sheet.

```
your_number = '412.5876'
ws['A1'] = float(your_number)
```

This should fix your problem.