# Openpyxl coverts numbers in CSV as text in XLSX file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, openpyxl

I have a series of CSV file like [this](https://gofile.io/?c=OBK7cz) one. I’m trying to convert and merge them into an xlsx file with python and openpyxl with this code:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import glob

csvpath = 'C:/Users/Lorenzo/Downloads/CSV/'
csvfiles = glob.glob(csvpath + '*.csv')
data = input('Inserisci data Simulazione: ')
destinationfilepath = 'C:/Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/Simulazione_' + data + '.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

for i in range(len(csvfiles)):
    filename = csvfiles[i]
    reader = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=',')
    csvname =  filename[len(csvpath):-4]
    ws1 = wb.create_sheet(csvname)
    k=0
    for row in reader:
        if k==0:
            ws1.append(row)
        else:
            g=0
            for cell in row:
                c= ws1.cell(row=k, column=g)
                c.value = float(cell)
                g=g+1
            k=k+1
    ws1['A1'] = 'Iteration'
    ws1['B1'] = 'CD'
    ws1['C1'] = 'CL'
    ws1['D1'] = 'CL_F'
    ws1['E1'] = 'CL_R'
    ws1['F1'] = 'CM'

sheet = wb['Sheet']
wb.remove(sheet)

wb.save(destinationfilepath)
```

The code runs but in most cells (and strangely enough not in all cells) I get the error “number stored as text” despite using the command *float* like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242385/openpyxl-numbers-stored-as-text) and similar topics.
What is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should check (and simplify your logic). `ws.cell(column=0, row=0)` will raise an exception in openpyxl because rows and columns are 1-indexed.

Comment: Add `print(row)` to see the failing Row. Then [edit] your question and show it along with the **Full Traceback**

Comment: @CharlieClark Thank you! That was the main problem. In addition the code was badly indented (I had to outdent `k=k+1` ).