# Openpyxl Ignore Errors in output workbook

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an entire workbook written with openpyxl and the only thing I can't seem to figure out is how to get rid of cell errors in the workbook.

This seems to be the module I'm interested in. I'd like to set the numbersStoredAsText parameter to True so I don't see the green error at the top corner of all my cells, but there's no real documentation or instructions on how to exactly call it for a workbook/worksheet. Any ideas?

openpyxl.worksheet.errors module
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.errors.html

Comment: Please take a look as this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242385/openpyxl-numbers-stored-as-text

This might help your scenario, you ask seems to need explicit type casting for converting the type from str to int / float

Comment: There's no need for documentation: just convert the numbers to strings.

Comment: My numbers in a specific column are strings (because I needed leading zero's)... that's why I'm getting the error for that column in the output workbook

Comment: numbersStoredAsText is not a parameter its the error that causes the green triangle at the top corner to show. The options to fix will be listed when clicking on the cell. So I think you can only do something like 1) Convert to a number (but loose the leading 0's which I guess you don't want. 2) Use the TEXT formula **=TEXT(A1,"0000000")**, padding with leading 0's or 3) disable error background checking on the workbook so the green error is not displayed.